# Screenshot in flutter web

Tags: flutter, screenshot, flutter-web

I'd like to know how I can screenshot a widget with flutter web. I already tried the package named screenshot but it seems to dont work on web.
Does anybody know how I can do that ?

Answer (score 2):

did you try this?

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
// import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
// import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          fontSize: 50,
        )),
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Screenshot Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //Create an instance of ScreenshotController
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Screenshot(
              controller: screenshotController,
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 5.0),
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                  ),
                  child: Text("This widget will be captured as an image")),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Capture Above Widget',
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                screenshotController
                    .capture(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 10))
                    .then((capturedImage) async {
                  ShowCapturedWidget(context, capturedImage!);
                }).catchError((onError) {
                  print(onError);
                });
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Capture An Invisible Widget',
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                var container = Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 5.0),
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "This is an invisible widget",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                    ));
                screenshotController
                    .captureFromWidget(
                        InheritedTheme.captureAll(
                            context, Material(child: container)),
                        delay: Duration(seconds: 1))
                    .then((capturedImage) {
                  ShowCapturedWidget(context, capturedImage);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<dynamic> ShowCapturedWidget(
      BuildContext context, Uint8List capturedImage) {
    return showDialog(
      useSafeArea: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Captured widget screenshot"),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: capturedImage != null
                ? Image.memory(capturedImage)
                : Container()),
      ),
    );
  }

  // _saved(File image) async {
  //   // final result = await ImageGallerySaver.save(image.readAsBytesSync());
  //   print("File Saved to Gallery");
  // }
}
```

dont forget to run `flutter pub add screenshot`

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to take screenshot and download it on Web can use the below code snippet. In case have doubts, comment it.

```
import 'dart:html' show AnchorElement;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;



Future<void> downloadScreenshotFn() async {
    final BuildContext? currentContext = screenshotKey.currentContext;
    if (currentContext == null) {
      return;
    }

    final RenderRepaintBoundary? boundary =
        currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
    if (boundary == null) {
      Widgets.showToast('Unable to share! Please take a screenshot');
      return;
    }
    final ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2);
    final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
    try {
      AnchorElement()
        ..href = Uri.dataFromBytes(pngBytes, mimeType: 'image/png').toString()
        ..download = 'Photo.png'
        ..style.display = 'none'
        ..click();
    } catch (e) {
      print('error while Downloading: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on a mobile browser

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't try on mobile browsers. I'm using that successfully on desktop browsers. Will take a look at this in case I need.

Comment: If you could get a solution that would be much appreciated